# Session variable being unset

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello guys and girls i have built a battle script but now i have noticed when i try adding a new sql update to it that it is not storing the gym leader in a session variable .
So the user goes to battle.php?gymleader=nick

Then i grab the nick and store it in a session variable after i esape it for sql injection etc.. Then i search the db to find out what monsters " nick " has then shows the monster and then the main battle script comes in. When they go to the gym it will take them to battle.php?gymleader=nick but then once they get into the battle it will just take them to battle.php so i think its storing the "nick" then the user picks a move then it redirects them to just battle.php then it stores the vairable again has nothing ??

The battle side of it works perfect just seems to be not storing $_SESSION['gymleader'] has i have said i think it stores ti twice. When the user first comes tot he page it sets it correct and then they pick a move and redirects them to battle.php and not battle.php?gymleader=nick then it sets the gymleader has nothing im guessing ??

Here is the battle script

```
<?php
include 'config.php'; 

print_r ($_SESSION);
/// Here we unset the win / lost status
unset($_SESSION['battle_won']); 
unset($_SESSION['battle_lost']); 



$_SESSION['gymleader'] = mysql_escape_string($_GET['gymleader']);


//// here we get the users first monster
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE belongsto='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND slot=1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$sql23 = "SELECT * FROM gyms WHERE leader='".$_SESSION['gymleader']."'";
$result23 = mysql_query($sql23) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get23 = mysql_fetch_array($result23);




/// Here we get the image of the pokemon and any other info we need
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `pokemon` WHERE `name` = '" . $battle_get['pokemon'] . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
    $values = mysql_fetch_array($result);




////// Now we make there hp up from there level
$a = $battle_get['level'] ;
$b = 5;
$hpofuserpokemon = ($a * $B) ;
///// We make a random number up to take the hp down by
srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
$random_number = rand(0,10);

srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
$random_number2 = rand(0,13);
?>
  <?php
unset($_SESSION['battle_won']); 
unset($_SESSION['battle_lost']); 
///// now we check to see if user is all ready in  a battle we don't want to fill up database with fake battles

$sql12 = "SELECT * FROM battle WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
$result12 = mysql_query($sql12) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get12 = mysql_fetch_array($result12);

/// Here we do if there is a result we echo out nothing. Else if there is no battles stored we make one for them seen has were nice
if  ($battle_get12['win'] == 1 )
  echo " ";
else

mysql_query("INSERT INTO battle 
(username, hp, win, pokemon1name, pokemon_pic, gympokemon1, gympokemon1hp, gympokemon1pic, levelofgym) VALUES('".$_SESSION['username']."','".$hpofuserpokemon."', 1,'".$battle_get['pokemon']."','http://www.pokemontoxic.net/Geodude.png' ,'".$battle_get23['gympokemon1']."','".$battle_get23['gympokemon1hp']."','".$battle_get23['gympokemon1pic']."','".$battle_get23['level']."' )
 ") or die(mysql_error());  

 $_SESSION['gymlevel'] = mysql_escape_string($battle_get23['level']);

?>
  <?php
//// Here we check if users hp is under 0 or 0 meaning there dead
if  ($battle_get12['hp']  < 0)
 {
   echo "You Lost the battle !!";


   mysql_query("DELETE FROM battle WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'")
or die(mysql_error());  
$_SESSION["battle_lost"] = 1 ;
 echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=battle_select.php?type=gym">';   

   die();

}
else {
print ("");
}
?>
  <?php
/// Here is the most inport thing if the gyms pokemon has less than 0hp we give them the money etc....
if  ($battle_get12['gympokemon1hp'] < 0)
 {
  $result3123123 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=money+60 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
or die(mysql_error());

$result3132131321 = mysql_query("UPDATE user_pokemon SET level=level+1 WHERE belongsto = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND slot=1 AND pokemon = '".$battle_get['pokemon']."'");

  $result31231236 = mysql_query("UPDATE battle SET onpokemon=onpokemon+1 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
or die(mysql_error());



$blah = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET '".$_SESSION['gymleader']."'='1'WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
or die(mysql_error());  



echo"You have won the battle. Please go back to the gym list to battle again.";
$_SESSION["battle_won"] = 1 ;
 echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=battle_select.php?type=gym">';   

    exit;    


   die();

}
else
  echo ""; 
?>
  <?php
//// Now we wanna check to see if user has pressed the button to attack i wonder if they have ?

if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
   /// we take hp from the player
  $hpdown = mysql_query("UPDATE battle SET hp=hp-".$random_number." WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
or die(mysql_error());
   /// at the same time we take hp from the enermy

   $enermy = mysql_query("UPDATE battle SET gympokemon1hp=gympokemon1hp-".$random_number2." WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'")
or die(mysql_error());



    }

?>
```

Has you can see im setting the gymleader session virable at the top of the page

```
$_SESSION['gymleader'] = mysql_escape_string($_GET['gymleader']);
```

But then when they are battling it will just refresh the page seen has its all on 1 page and re set it ?

And im getting a error on the new bit of the code i have added

```
$blah = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET '".$_SESSION['gymleader']."'='1'WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

But i guess that is because nothing is in side the session virable gymleader ?

session is started in config.php  with the sql connect

Comment: What does the error say exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You must start session first to save data into it. Use [php session_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: session is started in config.php

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();   //Insert this here.

print_r ($_SESSION);
/// Here we unset the win / lost status
unset($_SESSION['battle_won']); 
unset($_SESSION['battle_lost']);
```

You need to start session first before using it, destroying or unsetting it.

Comment: session is started in config.php